# No database connection via doctrine in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, xampp

I'm working on the symfony tutorial jobeet and I have problems to get a database connection to the MySQL-database via doctrine. Development enviroment: Mac OS X and XAMPP.

The command php `symfony doctrine:build-schema` gives me the following error message:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Users/xx/projects/myproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 470
>     PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

The database settings in the database.yml:

```
 all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_project_db'
      username: root
      password: root
```

MySQl is running. Username and password are correct. The database 'my_project_db' exists.

Could anybody give me a hint what's going wrong?

Comment: Does the /var/mysql/mysql.sock file exist? Try finding that file using locate if not.

Comment: yes. it's an empty file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to create a symlink in `/var/mysql` to your `mysql.sock`:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql /var/mysql
```

Comment: sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql /var/mysql

Answer (score 13):

Or with MAMP

```
cd /var; sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my apple mac and did the following:

```
cd /var; sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ mysql
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OSX Lion:

```
cd /var;
sudo mkdir mysql; cd mysql;
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

This situation also happened to me and I use MAMP Pro. If you use MAMP Pro, its worth checking the main window. Look at "MySQL" tab, and then see "Allow local access only" checkbox. If it is checked, you should uncheck it. Finally, click, "Apply" button.